# Can you split a visual studio project (c#) and reference it?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Not sure how to explain it but here goes.

I have 2 projects that reference SQLite.  1 is for Windows and 1 is for Windows Phone.

Now i need to create a class library for each platform, and reference the correct SQLite project for each.  Ideally i would like to create my code in one place and then reference it in each project.  Problem is my code uses SQLite.

I do not really want to have a separate copy in each project for each platform.

Can i do what i want, or not possible?

I only thought i maybe able to because if i create a windows application using cordova, it somehow creates 3 projects, 1 for windows, 1 for phone and the other has its shared resources in.

Here is a the sort of thing of what i would like

SQLite - Windows
SQLite - Phone

Library - Windows (references SQLite Windows)
Library - Phone (references SQLite Phone)
Library - Shared (shared code that both library projects can use)

Cordova - Windows (references Library Windows)
Cordova - Phone (references Library Phone)
Cordova - Shared (shared resources that both cordova projects can use)

This is all because the SQLite cannot run on both WIndows and Phone, so need a separate project for each

Comment: You can certainly create a project (or better, create a new solution) and build a base library for db connectivity.  Your applications can reference the specific DLL assemblies, and there would be no need to worry about including the project in your other solutions.  However, if all projects (3, in this case) are in the same VS Solution, this shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use file linking in the project.

---

This is an old Silverlight trick to share one set of code *between two projects* or two different versions of the CLR.

Create the code in project 1. Then for project 2, add the files by *linking* them from project 1. To do that type of add *link* this is the process:

The trick is to include as a link into the project. Here is how

1. In the second project right click and select `Add` then `Existing Item...` or <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>.
2. Browse to the location of the file(s) found in the first project and select the file(s).
3. Once the file(s) have been selected, then on the `Add` button select the drop down arrow.
4. Select `Add as link` to add the *common* files(s) as a link into the project.

   [image]

That will give access to the file *as if* the file was actually within the project, but the file physically resides elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

If you put the code you want shared into its own project, you can then reference that in your other two projects (Windows and Cordova).

This will allow you to only write the code that they share once, while keeping the platform specific code separate.

You can put them all in one solution in Visual Studio, to help keep everything together. This also lets you easily reference the shared project.

Answer (score 0):

You can:
1. create a base shared library referenced by the two projects (Windows and Windows Phone).
2. create two other libraries (that extends the base library) compiled for the specific platform.
3. on runtime you can load by reflection the right library you need on each project